# Fractional Subscripts?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, stoichiometry, solid-state-chemistry, notation

What is the physical meaning when we have an empirical formula with fractional subscripts such as $\ce{LiMn_{1-x}Fe_{x}PO4}$ $(0 \le x \le 1)$?

This an example of the paper the notation above is used:

Bai, J.; Hong, J.; Chen, H.; Graetz, J.; Wang, F. *J. Phys. Chem. C* **2015**, 119 (5), 2266–2276. DOI [10.1021/jp508600u](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp508600u).

Answer (score 4):

These indicate "[doping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_(semiconductor))" or [non-stoichiometric compounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stoichiometric_compound).

In this case, there's some fraction of Fe, and some fraction of Mn in a [lithium iron phosphate battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery). If I remember correctly, you need to dope a different ion to increase the conductivity of $\ce{LiFePO4}$.

See also here: [How are non-Stoichiometric compounds determined?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6913/how-are-non-stoichiometric-compounds-determined)

Comment: I think it is a bit more than that: the nomenclature here is used when the ($Mn$,$Fe$) site in the lattice is fully occupied, and $x$ is telling you how many have $Fe$ vs $Mn$ in the sample. This is indicating that there is a single phase across $LiMnPO_4$ to $LiFePO_4$, trading out $Mn$ for $Fe$.  Non-stoichiometry ($Mn$+$Fe$ isn't 1) would be indicated by a $\delta$.  If $Mn$ did not substitute perfectly for $Fe$, it might be shown as $LiMn_{1-x-\delta}Fe_{x}PO_4$.

Comment: Yes, that's a useful clarification. I agree that in this particular case, there's a single phase and x vs. 1-x is giving you a ratio of $\ce{Fe}$ to $\ce{Mn}$ in this compound. However, I think most people would consider this case as a part of the broader subset of non-stoichometry, since there's no simple integer to define the formula. The OP's title question referred to the *general* question of fractional subscripts, which does go to non-stoichiometry.